# Remove left padding of Alert

Tags: javafx, alert, javafx-8, padding

Consider this sample program which is adding a TabPane into an Alert. As you will see, there is a white padding on the left of the TabPane that I just cannot remove.

If anyone has any idea it will be great.

Code:

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AlertTest extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new HBox());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.NONE);
        alert.setTitle("");
        alert.initOwner(primaryStage);
        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane(new Tab("test"));
        tabPane.setPadding(Insets.EMPTY);
        alert.getDialogPane().setPadding(Insets.EMPTY);
        alert.getDialogPane().setContent(tabPane);
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

Visual : 
[image: Ugly left padding]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add css like this:

```
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new HBox());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    //add this 3 lines
    String css = Main.class.getResource("styles.css").toExternalForm();
    scene.getStylesheets().clear();
    scene.getStylesheets().add(css);

    ...
}
```

and in styles.css add

```
.dialog-pane:no-header .graphic-container {
    -fx-padding: 0; /* 10px 0px 0px 10px */
}
```

You can find more info about the default styles in file: `fxrt.jar!/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css`

and here is the result and [full code demo](https://github.com/varren/JavaFX---Remove-Padding-in-Alert-Dialog-/tree/master/src/sample):

[image]